# Edit user information through modal

Tags: php, iframe, modal-dialog, populate

I am developing a small Interrail Planner for me and my friends.
At the moment, I am trying to create a modal to edit/update the travelers information.

Firstly, I have made it in a separated file.
A **workflow**:

```
USER click on edit button   ---->    Redirects to a new windows with a small centered card   ------------    
--------->   USER updates/changes the traveler information and clicks on change   ---->   The PHP backend
extracts the inputs values and updates them into MySQL database (set in config.php)   ---->   USER is 
redirected pack to the original page (pass.php).
```

Now, I want it to appear like a modal. I have tried to do it but it ain't work.

The pass.php file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once('config.php');

    /* *** CHECK IF USER IS ALREADY LOGED IN | IF NOT, REDIRECT TO LOGIN PAGE *** */
    if(empty($_SESSION)){
        print '<script>location.href="index.php";</script>';
    }

    /* *** SET THE CONNECTON WITH THE TABLE IN DATABASE *** */
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM travelers";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


    /* *** POPULATE THE MODAL WITH THE TRAVELLER INFO *** */
    if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {

        $id=$_GET['id'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM travelers WHERE id=$id";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        while($traveler = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $name = $traveler['name'];
            $birth_date = $traveler['birth_date'];
            $street = $traveler['street'];
            $street_no = $traveler['street_no'];
            $pc_1 = $traveler['post_code_1'];
            $pc_2 = $traveler['post_code_2'];
            $post_city = $traveler['post_city'];
            $tax_no = $traveler['tax_no'];
            $ss_no = $traveler['ss_no'];
            $id_no = $traveler['id_no'];
            $pass_no = $traveler['pass_no'];
            $pass_type = $traveler['pass_type'];
            $exp_date = $traveler['exp_date'];
        }
    }


    /* *** EXTRACT THE NEW INPUTS AND UPDATE THE DATA BASE *** */
    if(isset($_POST['save-btn'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
    
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $birth_date = $_POST['birth-date'];
        $street = $_POST['street'];
        $street_no = $_POST['street-no'];
        $pc_1 = $_POST['postal-code-1'];
        $pc_2 = $_POST['postal-code-2'];
        $post_city = $_POST['postal-city'];
        $tax_no = $_POST['tax-no'];
        $ss_no = $_POST['ss-no'];
        $id_no = $_POST['id-no'];
        $pass_no = $_POST['pass-no'];
        $pass_type = $_POST['pass-type'];
        $exp_date = $_POST['pass-date'];
    
        $sql = "UPDATE travelers SET name='$name', birth_date='$birth_date', street='$street', street_no='$street_no', post_code_1='$pc_1', post_code_2='$pc_2', post_city='$post_city', tax_no='$tax_no', ss_no='$ss_no', id_no='$id_no', pass_no='$pass_no', pass_type='$pass_type', exp_date='$exp_date' WHERE id='$id'";
        
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        header('Location: pass.php');
        exit();
    }
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt_PT">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>IR PLANNER</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles\general_styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles\pass_styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
    </head>


    <body>
        <!-- <div id="fade" class="hide"></div> -->
        <header>
            <text>INTERRAIL PLANNER</text>
            <div class="nav_icons">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-house" onclick="goHome()" id="home"></i>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-right-from-bracket" onclick="buttonLogout()" id="logout"></i>
            </div>
        </header>

        <main>
            <div class="pass_holders_main">
                
                <?php
                    while($traveler=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "
                            <div class='pass-holder-info'>
                                <div class='header'>
                                    <div id='header-title'>
                                        <h2>PASSHOLDER $traveler[id]</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id='btns'>
                                        <a onclick='editTraveller()' id='edit-btn'>
                                            <i class='fa-regular fa-pen-to-square'></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='pass-body'>
                                    <div class='primary-info'>
                                        <div id='pass-name'>
                                            <label for='name'>Full Name:</label>
                                            <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='$traveler[name]' readonly>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id='pass-birth-date'>
                                            <label for='birth-date'>Birth Date:</label>
                                            <input type='date' name='birth-date' id='birth-date' value='$traveler[birth_date]' readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='fiscal-info'>
                                        <div class='first-line'>
                                            <div id='pass-street'>
                                                <label for='street'>Street:</label>
                                                <input type='text' name='street' id='street' value='$traveler[street]' readonly>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id='pass-no'>
                                                <label for='street-no'>No.:</label>
                                                <input type='text' name='street-no' id='street-no' value='$traveler[street_no]' readonly>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id='pass-post-code'>
                                                <label for='post-code'>Post Code:</label>
                                                <input type='text' inputmode='numeric' name='post-code' id='post-code-1' value='$traveler[post_code_1]' readonly>
                                                <label>-</label>
                                                <input type='text' inputmode='numeric' name='post-code' id='post-code-2' value='$traveler[post_code_2]' readonly>
                                                <label for='post-city' id='post-city-label'>City:</label>
                                                <input type='text' name='post-city' id='post-city' value='$traveler[post_city]' readonly>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='second-line'>
                                            <div id='pass-tax'>
                                                <label for='tax-no'>Tax Payer No.:</label>
                                                <input type='tax-no' inputmode='numeric' name='tax-no' id='tax-no' value='$traveler[tax_no]' readonly>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id='pass-ss'>
                                                <label for='ss-no'>Social Security No.:</label>
                                                <input type='text' inputmode='numeric' name='ss-no' id='ss-no' value='$traveler[ss_no]' readonly>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id='pass-id'>
                                                <label for='id-no'>ID No.:</label>
                                                <input type='text' name='id-no' id='id-no' value='$traveler[id_no]' readonly>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='pass-info'>
                                        <div id='pass-no'>
                                            <label for='pass-no'>Pass No:</label>
                                            <input type='text' name='pass-no' id='pass-no' value='$traveler[pass_no]'  readonly>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id='pass-type'>
                                            <label for='pass-type'>Pass Type:</label>
                                            <input type='text' name='pass-type' id='pass-type' value='$traveler[pass_type]' readonly>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id='pass-expiration'>
                                            <label for='exp-date'>Expiration Date:</label>
                                            <input type='date' name='exp-date' id='exp-date' value='$traveler[exp_date]' readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ";
                    }
                ?>

            </div>

        </main>
        

        <div id="fade" class="hide"></div>
        <form class="modal" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2>UPDATE TRAVELER INFORMATION</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="traveler-info">
                    <div id="name">
                        <label for="name">Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div id="birth-id">
                        <div>
                            <label for="birth-date">Birth Date:</label>
                            <input type="date" name="birth-date" id="birth-date" value="<?php echo $birth_date ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="id-no">Id No.:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="id-no" id="id-no" value="<?php echo $id_no ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tax-ss">
                        <div>
                            <label for="tax-no">Tax No.:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="tax-no" id="tax-no" value="<?php echo $tax_no ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="ss-no">SS No.:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="ss-no" id="ss-no" value="<?php echo $ss_no ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="street-1">
                        <div>
                            <label for="street">Street:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="street" id="street" value="<?php echo $street ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="street-no">No.:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="street-no" id="street-no" value="<?php echo $street_no ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="street-2">
                        <div>
                            <label for="postal-code-1">Postal Code:</label>
                            <input type="number" name="postal-code-1" id="postal-code-1" value="<?php echo $pc_1 ?>">
                            <label>-</label>
                            <input type="number" name="postal-code-2" id="postal-code-2" value="<?php echo $pc_2 ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="postal-city">City:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="postal-city" id="postal-city" value="<?php echo $post_city ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="pass">
                        <div>
                            <label for="pass-no">Pass No.:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="pass-no" id="pass-no" value="<?php echo $pass_no ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="pass-type">Type:</label>
                            <select name="pass-type" id="pass-type">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="<?php echo $pass_type ?>" selected><?php echo $pass_type ?></option>
                                <option value="7-d / 1-m">7-d / 1-m</option>
                                <option value="4-d / 1-m">4-d / 1-m</option>
                                <option value="5-d / 1-m">5-d / 1-m</option>
                                <option value="10-d / 2-m">10-d / 2-m</option>
                                <option value="15-d / 2-m">15-d / 2-m</option>
                                <option value="15 days">15 days</option>
                                <option value="22 days">22 days</option>
                                <option value="1 month">1 month</option>
                                <option value="2 months">2 months</option>
                                <option value="3 months">3 months</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="pass-date">Exp. Date:</label>
                            <input type="date" name="pass-date" id="pass-date" value="<?php echo $exp_date ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
                <div id="save">
                    <input type="submit" name="save-btn" id="save-btn" value="SAVE">
                </div>  
            </div>
        </form>

    
        <footer>
            <div>Developed by Ruben Rodrigues &#169; 2023</div>
        </footer>


        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script>
            const openModal = document.querySelector("#edit-btn");
            const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
            const fade = document.querySelector("#fade");

            const toggleModal = () => {
                [modal, fade].forEach((el) => el.classList.toggle("hide"));
            };

            [openModal, fade].forEach((el) => {
                el.addEventListener("click", () => toggleModal())
            });
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I have tried some help from YouTube, ChatGPT, some blog/articles, but nothing happens.
The code I have only works if I do it in separeted files.

I though doing it as an iframe element, i.e., build in another file and import it through iframe. However, how can I pass the $traveler['id'] into the iframe?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I noticed some bad habbits that occure in your code. For instance :

```php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM travelers WHERE id=$id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Here your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. I would rather use an SQL prepare followed by bindParam as such:

```php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM travelers WHERE id= :id";
    $sql = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindParam(":id",$id);
    $result = $sql->execute()->fetch(); //Only fetching one line
```

Or even better :

```php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM travelers WHERE id= ?";
    $sql = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result = $sql->execute([$id])->fetch(); //Only fetching one line
```

There are multiple ways to do so, but **never trust user's input !**

Secondly, instead of using :

```
"<?php echo $street ?>" //(Plus there is an error because you forgot the ";")
```

Simply use the  php tag :

```
"<?= $street ?>"
```

And you should not use this method :

```
<?php //Some code...
echo "<div>
          $variable
      </div>"; 
//Some code
?>
```

But instead :

```
<?php //Some code... ?>
    <div>
        <?= $variable ?>
    </div> 
<?php //Some code ?>
```

While in theory both methods lead to the same result, the first method is realy not convenient to read and should be avoided. A good PHP code is always easy to read as the language is built for it.

Doing so would alread make your code cleaner and clearer. And it would be easier for you and us to spot the errors.

For your question about the iframe, it's like opening a new tab on your browser. It's a completly different PHP script that is running a new HTTP request.

You can share it either by passing it throught a GET method or a POST. You can also use $_SESSION to share values.

But I have many questions for you :

1. What error do you get ? What is not working ?
2. If it works in separated files, it must be a conflict between your variables. Did you try to dump your already defined variables, make an include and see if it works ?
3. Why instead of bypassing the error not just trying to understand it ?